# How to accept only integers in a WPF textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Do you know how to restrict user input in textbox, this textbox only accepts integer? By the way I'm developing for Windows 8. I've tried what I searched from SO and from Google but it's not working,

Comment: Have you looked at the char.IsNumeric method..? checking this on the Key Press, or Key Down Events..?

Comment: yup i have a warning message keychar is not found

Comment: better show some code .. because there are KeyEvents that you can use to get that... if not perhaps you need to setup a Mask on that field

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to download the WPF ToolKit (which has both the IntegerUpDown control or a MaskedTextBox), you can implement it yourself as adapted from this article on [Masked TextBox In WPF](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rahul4_saxena/masked-textbox-in-wpf/) using the [**`UIElement.PreviewTextInput`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [**`DataObject.Pasting`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dataobject.pasting?view=netframework-4.7.2) events.

Here's what you would put in your window:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow" Title="MainWindow" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="100" Height="100"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">

        <TextBlock Name="NumericLabel1"  Text="Enter Value:"  />
        <TextBox   Name="NumericInput1" 
                   PreviewTextInput="MaskNumericInput" 
                   DataObject.Pasting="MaskNumericPaste"  />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And then implement the C# in your codebehind:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MaskNumericInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !TextIsNumeric(e.Text);
    }

    private void MaskNumericPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        {
            string input = (string)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string));
            if (!TextIsNumeric(input)) e.CancelCommand();
        }
        else
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }

    private bool TextIsNumeric(string input)
    {
        return input.All(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || Char.IsControl(c));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public class IntegerTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);

        Text = new String(Text.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
        this.SelectionStart = Text.Length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the most raw level you can intercept the `KeyUp` event or `TextChanged` to see what char is being added and remove it if it cannot be parsed to Int.

Also check - [Only accept digits for textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801430/only-accept-digits-for-textbox)
and [Masking Textbox to accept only decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209484/masking-textbox-to-accept-only-decimals)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a integer up down control. There's one in the WPF toolkit that will do the trick:

https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IntegerUpDown